# iOS Secure Text Input For UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

im making a Lib for online payment, which will be plugged in merchant's apps, in my Lib have a popup view with Textfield which letting the user to input their PIN code in it

As i think the merchant can write something to get the inputted key in their app in background when my view is show, so i would like to know if thats possible and how to prevent something like that?

Prevent something like capturing keyboard event without needing of textfield delegate like in [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099866/catch-text-input-without-textfield) or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267560/receive-iphone-keyboard-events)

Thanks

Comment: explain your question more what do you want?

Comment: I mean that i don't want any other keyboard related code (delegate or something) to capture the input, since it will be plugged in other app.

Im also not sure if there's a way to do this, really sorry if the question is confusing

Comment: Your issue still isn't clear. Are you asking about keeping app B from seeing the PIN entered into app A where app A is using your library? Or are you wanting to prevent the developer of the app using your library from seeing the PIN?

Comment: Both the app B running in background and app A which using my Lib

Comment: App B can't ever get the value but there really isn't any way to keep the developer using your library for their app from getting the value.

Comment: My advice to you - if you're dealing with credit cards, use a TRUSTED third party payment service like Stripe or PayPal. But in the end, since you're building with Objective-C, the only payment service Apple will _allow_ on the device is Apple's IAP.

Comment: thanks for the reply, im working for a payment company that using their own card, i guess i have to use the ownself make keyboard now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it difficult for the hosting app, but you will never be able to make it impossible to read the PIN. To make it difficult, you will need to create your own PIN entry with its own "keyboard" possibly similar to the PIN entry for the iOS lock screen. 
I would avoid using a keyboard, as users can insert their own keyboard, and thus wouldn't use any of the standard text entry fields. It shouldn't be too hard to create a matrix of 11 buttons (0-9 and a backspace) and the code to display it.

Comment: thanks! guess i have to make my own keyboard now